# How to power on a VM in azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-management

The title says it all. I've tried lots of things but I don't think any of them are worth mentioning. I have finally figured out to avoid Microsoft.WindowsAzure and have installed the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute and Microsoft.Azure.Common libraries.

I've finally got an authentication token like this:

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/deadbeef-beef-beef-beef-ec74557498e8");
var credential = new ClientCredential("beefbeef-beef-beef-beef-b1d3cf5d037d", "passwordpasswordpasswordpasswordpasswordpas=");
var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://www.url.com/servicename", credential);
```

But now I'm struggling to use the documentation to learn to power on my VMs. I'm not even sure exactly where to start. All I know is I'd like to avoid the REST API and keep my code in C#. I'm looking for something like:

```
using (var client = new ComputeManagementClient(creds)) {
    foreach (var vm in client.VMs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting VM: {0}", vm.Name);

        vm.PowerOn();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're dealing with ARM-based VMs, here's the code to start one.  "context" is ComputeManagementClient under the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute namespace

```
var result = VirtualMachinesOperationsExtensions.Start(context.VirtualMachines, azureResourceGroup, azureResourceName);
```

If you are dealing with with Classic VMs, here's the code to start one. "context" is ComputeManagementClient under the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute namespace

```
var result = context.VirtualMachines.BeginStarting(serviceName, deploymentName,
                        instanceName);
```

You can also avoid all of the headaches of writing your own code and monitoring it making sure it all works properly and use [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com/blog/how-to-automate-schedule-shutdowns-of-azure-vms/) to schedule startups and shutdowns of your Azure VMs. (I'm affiliated with the service)

Comment: Thank you so much! The `Microsoft.Azure` vs `Microsoft.WindowsAzure` thing has caused me no end of headaches. I appreciate the recommendation but I need to do this on-demand and in a manner integrated with some of our other internal systems.

Comment: Also, d'oh! The whole reason I wanted to comment was to say I can't make a one character edit but I think `VirtualMachineOperationsExtensions` should be `VirtualMachinesOperationsExtensions`. It might save someone a minute or two in the future.